# Jsp file not found

Tags: spring-boot, jsp, tomcat

I have to get the view of my jsp file using the url i have created. after resolving all recommended steps like adding tomcat embed dependency in my pom.xml file on my Spring Boot project. I'm still encountering this error [JSP file not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ThjY1.png)

Here is my code,

> ```
> @Controller
> public class HelloController {
>   @RequestMapping("say-hello")
>   @ResponseBody
>   public String sayHello() {
>           //http://localhost:8080/say-hello
>       return  "Hello!, what are you learning today?";
>   }
>   //http://localhost:8080/say-hello-html
>   @RequestMapping("say-hello-html")
>   @ResponseBody
>   public String sayHelloHtml() {
>   StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer();
>       sb.append("<html>");
>       sb.append("<head>");
>       sb.append("<title> My First HTML pagenochange </title>");
>       sb.append("</head>");
>       sb.append("<body>");
>       sb.append("My First HTML page body - Not Changed");
>       sb.append("</body>");
>       sb.append("</html>");
>       return sb.toString();
>   }
>       
>     @RequestMapping("say-hello-jsp")
>     public String sayHelloJsp() {
>          return "SayHelloJsp";    
>     }
> }
> ```

I added this dependency in my pom file. But no change.

```
                <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: This question should include more details and clarify the problem, and provide [mcve].

Comment: The answer is already in the JSP file path in the error message.